# What NoSQL database can do a tree type structure unlimited with depth does it exist?

Tags: mysql, tree, nosql

i tried Mongodb but its just 100 levels deep not sure if its still true

i was thinking of just using json instead directly and store it on any database as a blob.

basically a noSQL.

Comment: Check the [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

Comment: walter i will check it out! thanks